# Python while loop reading serial data not exiting after pressing Ctrl + C

Tags: python, linux, arduino, signals, pyserial

I have the following Python 3.9 while True loop that reads data coming from a Teensy 4.1 that does not exit after pressing "Ctrl + C".

Only "Ctrl + \" and "Ctrl + Z" stop/pause the execution of the program.

```
data = ""

while True:
    data += ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode("utf-8")

    if (not data.endswith("\n")) or data == "":
        continue

    print(data)
    data = ""
```

Adding a try-except block around the line that reads data also does not work:

```
data = ""

while True:
    try:
        data += ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode("utf-8")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("stopped")
        exit()

    if (not data.endswith("\n")) or data == "":
        continue

    print(data)
    data = ""
```

How do I ensure that Ctrl + C will stop the execution of the program?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not going to work, unless you are going to do something with threads. The reason is that "normal" python is single threaded. Your `ser.read` is busy "outside" python and cannot accept the SIGINT (= ctrl+C) signal. If you send it a SIGQUIT (= ctrl+\) signal, the `ser.read` terminates and your scripts terminates.